# How can I turn off location services system-wide?

Tags: settings

I'm trying to locate setting to turn on/off location services system-wide. Is there any way to to achieve that in elementary OS?

Answer (score 1):

No, there doesn't appear to be a system-wide service to toggle (in `/etc/init` or `/usr/bin`), though elementary does have two open tickets for creating one: [Add location settings](https://bugs.launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-security-privacy/+bug/1446770) and [Create a GeoClue2 "Agent"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1606052). There are open bounties [for](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/11805701-add-location-settings) [both](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/36308400-create-a-geoclue2-agent), if you would like to contribute.